# Load a flash after hitting a button

Tags: javascript, css, flash

I am building a website with my school work (dreamfoxgames.com).

If you click on a button called "play" a popup/Modal will come with the game in flash or unity plugin. My problem is that when a visitor loads the page they will automatic load the flash file. This means that the music will start and the page will be slow with loading (all those games).

Is there a way to only load the flash player after somebody hit the play button?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, load the needed html (with the flash) with an ajax call when the page is ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can also be done using an embed element (no need for external api):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashEmbed = null;
    function startFlash() {
    if(flashEmbed != null) {
        document.getElementById("flashContainer").removeChild(flashEmbed);
    }
    flashEmbed = document.createElement("embed");
    document.getElementById("flashContainer").appendChild(flashEmbed);
    flashEmbed.src="Flashfile.swf";
    flashEmbed.type="application/x-shockwave-flash";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="startFlash()">start flash</button>
<div id="flashContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, the only problem is that everytime when somebody hit the button there will be a new flash embed

Comment: I have modified the code so there is no more than one embed at one time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) to load swf content in div.

Suppose if you have a div in your html as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script> 
    <script>
</head> 
<body>
      <div id="myContent">
        swf will be embedded here
      </div>
     <button onclick="playSwf()">Click to play swf</button>
</body>
</html>
```

To play the swf..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function playSwf()
    {
       //Syntax  
       //swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrl, id, width, height, version,
      //                    expressInstallSwfurl, flashvars, params,
     //                     attributes, callbackFn)

         //optional parameters omitted
         swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf", "myContent", "400", "400","10"); 

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks! but for some reason this code doesnt work really good with bootstrap.