# Using jquery to load and play a flash file

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, flash

I have a client that has one of those overlay flash videos that "walks out" on screen and talks and then leaves. While I know this is very dated and we have explained this, the client insists on having it.

How do I load and play an animation on a button click using jquery?

Comment: You can use the `ExternalInterface` class in AS3 to communicate between Javascript and AS3.  Type it into your search engine to find one of the many tutorials about it.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720212/load-a-flash-after-hitting-a-button